# Can't make a Jquery Table Cell Click work

Tags: jquery

On a web-page I have an HTML select and a DIV-styled box. The HTML select has three values (this week, next week and next next week as numbers). When I select a week (e.g. this week) the HTML select's OnChange function starts an AJAX script, which loads the DIV-styled box with a PHP-created table, which again contains an extract from a MySQL database for the actual week.  This part functions well. But I can't implement a jQuery Cell Click function on that "table".

I have tried:

```
// Jquery - reset/clear part..
$("#table").Click()
// {xxx}  --  Does not work

// Jquery - reset/clear part..
$("#table tr td").Click()
// {xxx}  --  Does not work
```

I have tried "ordinary" JavaScript functions. Does not work...

Is it because the table are created dynamically (from the PHP-script) - meaning jQuery works only on static tables - and what do I have to do to make it work?

Here's the codes:

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <style type="text/css">
    .pos22 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 150px;
      top: 25px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 25px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .pos1 {
      position: Absolute;
      left: 50px;
      top: 100px;
      width: 140px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .pos2 {
      position: Absolute;
      left: 190px;
      top: 100px;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 235px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    TR {
      height: 25px;
    }

    TD {
      height: 25px;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: Center;
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function showUser(str) {
      if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
  </script>

</head>

<?php

    $uge = date(W);
    $uge1 = $uge +1;
    $uge2 = $uge +2;

    ?>

  <body>
    <form>
      <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">Velg en UGE:</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $uge ?>">Uge
          <?php echo $uge ?>
        </option>
        <option value="<?php echo $uge1 ?>">Uge
          <?php echo $uge1 ?>
        </option>
        <option value="<?php echo $uge2 ?>">Uge
          <?php echo $uge2 ?>
        </option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint" class="pos2"><b>Table data goes here. </b></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

And here is the GETUSER.PHP part:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style class="text/css">
    .scroll {
      position: absolute;
      left: 140px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 800px;
      /* 500px */
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 12px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .tab3 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 140px;
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 12px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    table {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <?php
    $klokke = array("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","00");
    $dage   = array(" ","Mandag","Tirsdag","Onsdag","Torsdag","Fredag","Lordag","Sondag");

    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $year = date(Y);
    $week_no = $q;
    $week_start = new DateTime();

        echo"<div id='result'>11 </div>";  /* test later delete */

        echo "<div class= 'tab3'>";
        echo "<TABLE width='140px;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1'>";
            echo "<TBODY>";
            echo "<TR style='height: 25px;'>";
            echo "<TD width='140px'>&nbsp;</td>";
            echo "</TR>";
            for ($n = 1; $n <= 7; $n++)
            {
                echo "<TR style='height: 25px;'>";
                $week_start->setISODate($year,$week_no,$n);
                echo "<TD width='140px'>".$dage[$n]." ".$week_start->format('d-M')."</td>";
                echo "</TR>";
            }
            echo "</TBODY>";
        echo "</TABLE>";

        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='scroll'>";
            echo "<TABLE id='dattab' width='2400px;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1'>";
            echo "<TBODY>";
            echo "<TR style='height: 25px;'>";
            for ($col = 1; $col <= 24; $col++)
            {
                echo "<TD width='120px;'>".$klokke[$col-1].":00-".$klokke[$col].":00</TD>"; 
            }
            echo "</TR>";
            for ($row = 1;$row <= 7; $row++)
            {
                echo "<TR style='height: 25px;'>";
                for ($col = 1; $col <= 24; $col++)
                {
                    echo "<TD width='120px;'>C".$col."R".$row."</TD>";
                }
                echo "</TR>";
            }
            echo "</TBODY>";
            echo "</TABLE>";
        echo "</div>";
    ?>
</body>

</html>

<!--
    /*
     to be inplemented later !

    $ c on = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
    if (! $ con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($ c on,"ajax_demo");
    $ s q l="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
    $resu lt = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Hometown</th>
    <th>Job</th>
    </tr>";
    while($ r ow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);

    */
    -->
```

Comment: It should be `.click()` not `.Click()`, javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: If `$("#table").Click()` is really what you tried, then it's not working - and should report an error in the console - because there is no `Click()` method (instead it's `click()`); case-sensitivity is important. Pending an update/response I won't close this question as off-topic (as a typo), but I suspect that's the fault based on my first reading of the question.

Comment: Sorry mu fault.  .Click should be   .click() ..   Syntax is /was  correct in tested code

Comment: No, I have tried several methods (including the .click()  method .   It was an error writing the .click() as .Click . In the tested code it was .click() , I wrote itwrong in the question- my fault.

Comment: click not working after table refreshed with ajax request. is it true?

Comment: YES, it's not working...

Comment: @isherwood, that's most likely **not** why it's not working. I suspect they need to use delegate binding as they are replacing `innerHTML` with the results of the http request. @Kris, `$('body').on('click', '#table td', function(){/* your code here */})` will probably work

Comment: Just noticed: `#table` will never work, as their `<table>` doesn't have `id="table"`. :) @Kris, use `#dattab` instead of `#table`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$('#txtHint').on('click', 'table td', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: In this case you'd need to restructure to use event delegation, since `#txtHint` isn't available yet: `$(document).on('click, '#txtHint td', function() {...}`

Comment: @isherwood `#txthint` always there. Not putting after ajax request. so it doesn't matter. Created a fiddle for test: https://jsfiddle.net/ovaLshqy/

Comment: Not if the script falls before it in the document. Not sure from the question.

Comment: Thanks That did the JOB. IT works perfectly. Thanks a lot ( more than a billion) and you saved my day.  Kris

Comment: WHAT HAS HAPPENED HERE ????   I HAVE NOT COPIED NOR DUPLICATED THAT QUESTION . Something has gone completely crazy ....

Comment: That's mean this question is same with your. Yes you didn't copy but you can find your solution on that question too. More search before ask a question :)